# Visual Studio Installer 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a way I could download Visual Studio 2019, what happened was I deleted the folder and now the Installer thinks that I have Visual Studio 2019 and won't let me download it, if I try to delete it it says sorry something went wrong?

I tried deleting it and it didnt work I even re-installed the entire installer but no luck.

I really do need 2019.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: More advice here: [uninstall-visual-studio-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and here: [troubleshoot-installation-issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/troubleshoot-installation-issues?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link given by topsail.  If you can't find what you need, then try the following.

As you go through this, make sure you take notes of what you have done in case you need more help.

Microsoft provides a utility called the "Visual Studio Installer Cleanup Tool," which you can use to remove any traces of a previously installed Visual Studio.

You can manually remove the registry entries.

This is dangerous, so take a backup of your registry.

Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup.

navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup.

Delete any keys related to Visual Studio 2019.
Navigate to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup.

Again, delete any keys related to Visual Studio 2019.

Make sure you've deleted the Visual Studio 2019 folder from both "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" (if applicable).

Microsoft provides an official Visual Studio Uninstaller tool. Download and run it to remove any remaining traces of Visual Studio 2019. (Belts and braces)

Of course, if the you still have problems, then try contacting Microsoft Support.

Just to warn you again, if you don’t already know about the registry, make sure you back up your registry before making any changes.

If everything has worked, you should be able to reinstall.

I hope it works.